# How to specify temp-dir in rsync on remote machine

Tags: linux, rsync

I am copying file from my source machine dir to target machine

On the target machine I want to specify temp-dir /storage/tmp so that files are first copied there and then to the target dir /storage/files

I have defined a rsync module [target-path] in `rsyncd.conf`. Target-path has path set as `/storage/files`

Here is my command:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -az --include-from=$PUT_FILES --temp-dir=../tmp --exclude '*' /storage/source ${MY_TARGET_IP}::target-path
```

But it gives me error:

> rsync: mkstemp "/../tmp/sia.txt.Wgu8Ej" (in target-path) failed: No such file or directory (2)

How do I specify temp-dir /storage/tmp on my target machine?

Comment: The error says `/../tmp/sia.txt.Wgu8E` cannot be made. This means you are trying to rsync in to the root directory of the remote machine where it cannot traverse to the `tmp` directory to make the temp file. Try using an absolute path for the temp-directory for your first attempts.

Comment: the thing is since target-path is specified as a module in rsyncd.conf, that becomes the base dir in remote. This path is /storage/files. For tmp dir i want /storage/tmp. I cant seem to find a way to specify that. It always gives error

Comment: I suspect you cannot traverse out of the specified `path` directory. Is there a reason for avoiding the temp writes into `/storage/files` area? If it suits you, investigate the `--inplace` option to avoid tmp files.

Comment: the problem with having in /storage/files is that sometimes I see rsync not cleaning tmp files.. so they accumulate and use up space which could causes issues. Basically I have 2 machines. rsync on one machine is triggered after certain interval and it keeps /storage/files synced up between these two machines. I can create temp dir on the machine that triggers rsync since it is local. I am having issues with remote machine.